# RecyclerView doesnt update

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have the Adapter class and MainActivity.
when i click the Button its add new Worker, but the RecyclerView dosent update with the new worker. only the first worker add Successfully the next time i want to add worker its not update..

Adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private List<Worker> workerList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter() {
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Worker> workerList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.workerList = workerList;
    }

    public List<Worker> getWorkerList() {
        return workerList;
    }

    public void setWorkerList(List<Worker> workerList) {
        this.workerList = workerList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // responsible for creating new view holders for your items

        View itemView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Binds the data from your dataset to the views within the view holder
        Worker worker = workerList.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(worker.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // Returns the total number of items in your dataset
        return workerList.size();
    }
    public void update(List<Worker> data) {
        workerList.clear();
        workerList.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // Holds references to the views within the item layout
        TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.worker_details);       }
    }
}
```

Activity class:
I delete most of the code, and upload only the nessary parts..

````
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   
    Button save;                                                // save new worker
    ArrayList<Worker> Workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView; //????????????????
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); //????????????????
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);                     

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); //????????????????
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,Workers); //????????????????

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           // after push the button save its saves the inputs that entered by the user

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                
                if() {   
                }
                else {
**                    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter); //????????????????
**

                    if(Worker.ExChange(getInputOne) == 0) {
                    }
                    else {
                        Workers.add(new Worker(0, getInput,getInputOne,spinnerTeam.getSelectedItem().toString(),Worker.ExChange(getInputOne), (int) 0,"X","X"));
                        spinnerTeam.setSelection(0);
                    }
                    totlHoursUpdating.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(sumHours(Worker.ExChange(getInputOne))));
                    WorkerNameInput.setText(null);
                    WorkerTimeInput.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

First, you should run `recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);` immediately after finding `recyclerView` and initializing `myAdapter`. It is not recommended and not necessary to rerun `recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter)` if `myAdapter` has always been itself!

Next, you should pay closer attention to the documentation of the `RecyclerView` tutorial. The magic at `notifyDataSetChanged();`. As in your example would be the `update` function. If you want to manage the `workerList` outside the `adapter`, add an overloaded `update` function like this:

```java
public void update() {
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Finally, add a call to `myAdapter.update();` after you change `Workers`, which here would be after the line `Workers.add(new Worker(...`).

---

Folow below code:

MyAdapter.java

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private List<Worker> workerList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter() {
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Worker> workerList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.workerList = workerList;
    }

    public List<Worker> getWorkerList() {
        return workerList;
    }

    public void setWorkerList(List<Worker> workerList) {
        this.workerList = workerList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // responsible for creating new view holders for your items

        View itemView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Binds the data from your dataset to the views within the view holder
        Worker worker = workerList.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(worker.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // Returns the total number of items in your dataset
        return workerList.size();
    }
    public void update(List<Worker> data) {
        workerList.clear();
        workerList.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // see it
    public void update() {
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // Holds references to the views within the item layout
        TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.worker_details);       }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   
    Button save;                                                // save new worker
    ArrayList<Worker> Workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView; //????????????????
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); 
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);                     

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,Workers);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter); // see it

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           // after push the button save its saves the inputs that entered by the user

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                
                if() {   
                }
                else {
                    if(Worker.ExChange(getInputOne) == 0) {
                    }
                    else {
                        Workers.add(new Worker(0, getInput,getInputOne,spinnerTeam.getSelectedItem().toString(),Worker.ExChange(getInputOne), (int) 0,"X","X"));
                        
                        myAdapter.update(); // see it

                        spinnerTeam.setSelection(0);
                    }
                    totlHoursUpdating.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(sumHours(Worker.ExChange(getInputOne))));
                    WorkerNameInput.setText(null);
                    WorkerTimeInput.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: thank you but it still not update. maybe "2023-12-23 11:31:52.912  5409-5409  RecyclerView            com.example.myapplication_newerjava  E  No adapter attached; skipping layout" this is the cause..

Comment: see my new edit and do it again in your code.